# powershell command to get the count of a column in excel based on another column

Tags: excel, powershell

I want the count a column based on another column using powershell.
Example:

```
name group
x     a
y     a
z     b
c     c
a     a
v     a
```

I want to get like how many names(count) belong to each group. Is there any process in powershell without using foreach loop?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame trying to do this in Powershell, if UNIX/Linux commandline gets this done very easily:

```
awk '{print $2}' test.csv | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: I wanted the answer in powershell, i know that there is a way in UNIX/linux.